# Can i redownload a single file from a Torrent?

Tags: bittorrent

So, i downloaded a Torrent with a few video files, but seems like one of them got damaged(You are seeing it, and then at one moment the image distorts, and returns). I'm not sure if this is because the original file was like this, or if there was a problem with the download, so, Is there a way to erase only that video file, and have the Torrent client download it again? I'm using BitTorrent, but i can change to another if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Delete that one video from the downloaded folder that you want to download again.

Then you have to import your torrent file to BitTorrent, and the download should start. BitTorrent might begin with verifying the downloaded files, but once it detects that a file is missing (the one you deleted), it will start downloading.

Comment: To add to this, some torrent clients check the hash/checksum against the one provided on the torrent link so if there is any corruption, the hash *should* mismatch and it should re-download the blocks which are corrupt. If the checksums match OK and it's still corrupt, the file in the torrent was corrupt to begin with. However slightly unrelated but I've noticed on older hardware, higher res videos (and encodings such as h265) become severly artifacted as it cannot play them very well (i'm talking very old, single core laptops with no GPU) - this may be the problem also...

Comment: Sorry it took a lot to answer, but i had a hell of a day, and couldn't test it until now. So i had a little hard to understand how to do the steps, but at last i went with: Copy magnet link, erase Torrent, erase specific files, open magnet with navigator, load torrent, wait until it checks and download the files. Not sure if this was the method you said, but is how i understood it. Thanks!